# Is there a way to identify a species of tree?

Tags: genetics, botany

My family has been passing down  seeds from a lemon tree for about 3 generations now, There is some controversy about its origin or species. The lemons look like tangerines and when cut the pulp is very orange but are sour just like lemons. People always think we dye the lemonade. We have asked family members where our family got the original seed from and some say it was from Vera Cruz, Mexico but other family members say it might have came from Hawaii. Regardless it appears to have been from a tropical region. Is there a way a seed or part of a tree can be tested? If so, how much can I expect it to cost and where could I get it done?

Comment: Images would be helpful. We can try to identify it here, asking where to get it tested is not really on topic here.

Comment: True, true...but I don't have the tree physically with me and I ate all then lemons, lol. Sending a seed to a lab maybe?

Comment: I don't think OP is asking us to identify the species. He is asking for a test that will confirm the species of the plant. @MrHons Genetic tests should tell you the species. You can do a 16S rRNA sequencing. The cost shouldn't be very high but if you have a friend working in a bio-lab then you can ask for a little favour.

Comment: @WYSIWYG You could make an answer out of your comment if you want especially if you extend it to add a link to who the OP could send the tissue sample to for sequencing and analysis